# Cannot find styles - Where is the Style Sheet?

Tags: forms

I'm able to adjust the Column Width and Height using the "Inspect Tool" in Chrome.  I can't find where this is controlled.  Not an experiences ExpressionEngine user.

Can someone help?  [www.isonas.com](http://www.isonas.com) I would like to expand column 4 to about 500 and reduce the height to about 376 and then reduce the width of column 3 from 160 to about 80... the overall footer to about 375...

Answer (score 1):

The appearance of an EE site is determined solely by the CSS applied to the site - EE itself does not mess with how the site looks.

A quick squint at your site suggests that you are using primarily a css file located at `/css/style.css` to control the look of the site, and I suggest you begin your search for where / how to edit with that file.

It looks like you use a lot of other vendor CSS files too and a number of element level style over-rides, so it might be more complicated to get the look you want simply by editing the main file.

To fix the footer, you'll need to remove one of the element-level style overrides - currently the footer layout is controlled by this tag:

```
<div class="container float" style="min-height: 643px;">
```

Which suggests whatever else you have set in your CSS file, the footer is going to be at least 643px high...

Good luck with your edits.

> PS - If you get stuck with the ExpressionEngine implementation itself
> you'll make it easier for others here to help you if you include
> details of what version of EE you are using - there are major
> differences between EE2, EE3, EE4 and EE5 which affects how you fix
> some issues.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will see what I can find! and try to ask better questions in the future!